# Как перемножить 2 матрицы разных размеров

Tags: c++, матрицы

```
#include <iostream>

struct InputParameters {
    double vodka = 1.0;
    double rain = 1.0;
    double frend = 0.0;
};

int activationFunc(double x) {
    double xArgument = x;
    double value = 0.5;
    if (xArgument < value) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    InputParameters obj;

    double matrix[1][3] = { obj.vodka, obj.rain, obj.frend };

    double wightsInputToHiden1[1][3] = { 0.25, 0.25, 0.25 };
    double wightsInputToHiden2[1][3] = { 0.5, -0.4, 0.9 };

    double wightsInputToHiden[2][3] = {
        {wightsInputToHiden1[0][1],
         wightsInputToHiden1[0][2],
         wightsInputToHiden1[0][3]},

        {wightsInputToHiden2[0][1],
         wightsInputToHiden2[0][2],
         wightsInputToHiden2[0][3]}};

    int wightsHidenToOutput[1][2] = { -1, 1 };

    const int n = 2;
    const int m = 3;
    int hidenImput[n][m];
    const int rows = 1;
    const int columns = 3;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            for (int x = 0; x < rows; ++x) {
                for (int y = 0; y < columns; ++y) {
                //ошибка примерно здесь но непонятно как ее исправить
                hidenImput[i][j] += matrix[x][y] * wightsInputToHiden[x][y];
                }
            }
            std::cout << hidenImput[i][j];
        } 
    }
    std::cout << "\n";

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Как перемножить 2 матрицы разного размера пытался сделать по примеру из интернета но нашел только если они одинакового размера. Выводит мусор в консоли.

Comment: Перемножать можно только матрицы с одинаковым числом столбцов у первой и строк у второй - AxB и BxC, при этом получается матрица AxC...

Comment: А как можно перемножить входные параметры на веса при этом результат этих вычислений переместить в новый массив?

Comment: Мне ничего не говорит "входные параметры на веса" - сформулируйте с терминах матриц...

Answer (score 1):

Перемножать можно только матрицы с одинаковым числом столбцов у первой и строк у второй - `MxN` и `NxK`, при этом получается матрица `MxK`...

Простейший алгоритм - по определению умножения:

```
double A[M][N], B[N][K], C[M][K];

for(int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < K; ++j)
    {
        C[i][j] = 0.0;
        for(int k = 0; k < N; ++k)
            C[i][j] += A[i][k]*B[k][j];
    }
```

Вот, так как-то...

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>

struct InputParameters {
    double vodka = 1.0;
    double rain = 1.0;
    double frend = 0.0;
};

int activationFunc(double x) {
    double xArgument = x;
    double value = 0.5;
    if (xArgument < value) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

int main() {
    InputParameters obj;

    double matrix[3] = {obj.vodka, obj.rain, obj.frend};

    double wightsInputToHiden1[1][3] = {0.25, 0.25, 0.25};
    double wightsInputToHiden2[1][3] = {0.5, -0.4, 0.9};

    double wightsInputToHiden[2][3] = {
        {wightsInputToHiden1[0][0],
         wightsInputToHiden1[0][1],
         wightsInputToHiden1[0][2]},

        {wightsInputToHiden2[0][0],
         wightsInputToHiden2[0][1],
         wightsInputToHiden2[0][2]}};

    int wightsHidenToOutput[1][2] = {-1, 1};

    const int n = 2;
    const int m = 3;
    double hidenImput[n][m];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            hidenImput[i][j] = 0;
            hidenImput[i][j] += matrix[j] * wightsInputToHiden[i][j];
        } 
    }
    std::cout << "[ ";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (int j = 0; j < m; ++j) {
            std::cout << hidenImput[i][j] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << std::endl << " ";
    }
    std::cout << "]" << "\n";
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

О да удалось перемножить)) Надеюсь правильно все сделал